# Sentença dinamica usando array no JS

Tags: javascript, array, dynamic

Preciso escrever dinamicamente usando array: "Este site foi feito com HTML, CSS e JavaScript". Porém não consigo, aparece apenas o último valor do array. E não sei se estou fazendo corretamente de modo que o "e" fique certo quando adicionar mais linguagens. Só consigo fazend 'hard-coding'. Alguém consegue me ajuda? Obrigada :)

```
const codingLanguages = ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript", "Python", "Java", "C++"]

for (let i = 0; i < codingLanguages.length; i++) {
   document.getElementById('footerjs').innerHTML = `<p>This page was built using: ${codingLanguages[i]}, ${codingLanguages[i]} and ${codingLanguages[i]}.</p>`;
}
```

Comment: pq não cria umaa variável fora do for com a parte fixa (`var texto = '<p>This page was built using: '`) e depois dentro do `for` vai ajuntando os conteudos `texto += ',${codingLanguages[i]}'` depois exibe a mensagem fora do `for` (`document.getElementById('footerjs').innerHTML = texto`) ... com fazer o "and" no lugar da vírgula e fechar a tag `<p>`, deixo para você pensar um pouco :)

Comment: Demorei um pouquinho mas com a ajuda dos métodos da solução seguinte consegui resolver usando essa solução com loops. Muito obrigada :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizando `array.pop` podemos remover a última linguagem e guardá-la numa variável. Depois, utilizando `array.join` podemos concatenar todos as linguagens do array numa string separadas por ", ". No final, concatenamos " and" seguido da última linguagem.

Veja o seguinte snippet:

```js
const lastCodingLanguage = codingLanguages.pop();
const codingLanguagesString = `${codingLanguages.join(', ')} and ${lastCodingLanguage}`;

document.getElementById('footerjs').innerHTML = `<p>This page was built using: ${codingLanguagesString}</p>`
```

Comment: Foi ótima essa solução só com os métodos. Me ajudou para outra coisa também, Muito obrigada!  :)